# div position based on scroll position

Tags: javascript, scroll

I would like my logo to scroll up and down vertically based on the scroll position on the website.

In exactly the same way a default scroll bar indicates your position on the site, I would like my logo to do the same. When you are at the top of the website page, the logo sits at the top, and when you are at the bottom it will sit at the bottom of the page in a vertical bar on the left hand side of the web page.

I have no idea how to approach this, I have looked at a few plugins but none offer the positioning based on the content and I can't find any other Stack Overflow results that are what I am looking for, though I may not be phrasing the question correctly.

My setup is

```
.logo-scroll {
    position: fixed;
    border: 2px solid white;
    top: 30px;
    left: 30px;
    height: calc(100vh - 60px);
    width: 75px;
}  

.scroll-text {
    height: auto;
} 

.logo-scroll .scroll-text img {
    padding: 0 6px 0 17px;
}
```

and my html

```
<div class="logo-scroll">

    <div class="scroll-text">
        <a href="/home">
            <img src="logo.svg"/>
        </a>
    </div>

</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

** Edit - to complicate things, I have a 30px border which is not to be included in the page height. So an offset of 30px on the top and bottom.

The size of the margin/border will need to change responsively at break points - 1 maybe 2, before I will hide it. Essentially the height of the scroll bar will always need to match the height of either the page with margins subtracted or the height of the :before element.

Alternatively if I can set offsets, I can reuse the JS and adjust based on screen size. Like media queries for JS?

You can see the web page here - which is still very under construction https://www.sheree-new.shereewalker.com/

Answer (score 2):

You could give something like this a try.

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', e => {
  const logo = document.querySelector('.scroll-text');
  const logoHeight = logo.clientHeight;
  const viewHeight = window.innerHeight;
  const maxLogoOffset = viewHeight - logoHeight;
  const scrollFraction = getElementScrollFraction(document.querySelector('body'));
  logo.style.top = maxLogoOffset*scrollFraction;
});

function getElementScrollFraction(elem){
  return elem.scrollTop / (elem.scrollHeight - elem.clientHeight);
}
```

You'll also need to add `position:fixed;` to the `.scroll-text` css.

Here is a working example: https://jsbin.com/yuholihece/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution.

**Edited:**

```
const docHeight = Math.max(document.documentElement.scrollHeight, document.body.scrollHeight);
const logo = document.querySelector('.scroll-text');
const logoHeight = logo.offsetHeight;
// to get the pseudoelement's '#page::before' top we use getComputedStyle method
const barTopMargin = parseInt(getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('#page'), '::before').top);

let viewportHeight, barHeight, maxScrollDist, currentScrollPos, scrollFraction;

logo.style.top = barTopMargin + 'px';

window.addEventListener('load', update);
window.addEventListener('resize', setSizes);
document.addEventListener('scroll', update);

setSizes();


function update() {
    currentScrollPos = Math.max(document.documentElement.scrollTop, document.body.scrollTop);
    scrollFraction = currentScrollPos / (docHeight - viewportHeight);

    logo.style.top = barTopMargin + (scrollFraction * maxScrollDist) + 'px';
}

function setSizes() {
    viewportHeight = window.innerHeight;
    // to get the pseudoelement's '#page::before' height we use getComputedStyle method
    barHeight = parseInt(getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('#page'), '::before').height); 
    maxScrollDist = barHeight - logoHeight;
    update();
}
```

And if I understand correctly, you want `#page::before` element to have like margins on its top, left, bottom and right. If so, then I think it would be better to use this styling rules:

```
#page::before {
    content: "";
    position: fixed;
    top: 30px;
    bottom: 30px;
    left: 30px;
    right: 30px;
    ...
}
```

When you use `position: fixed` property (or `position: absolute`), you can stretch the element's width and height as you want by just setting `top` - `bottom` and `left` - `right` properties at the same time.
P. S.: And also there is no sense in using `display: inline-block`, because `position: fixed` (and `position: absolute`) automatically sets `display` to `block` :)

Hopefully, this helps you!

Comment: Hi Andrew, thank you so much. So this gets the ball rolling but it's moving the entire .scroll-text div, not just the logo inside. However if I change the line in the JS to:

const logo = document.querySelector('.scroll-text'); - rather than, .logo-scroll, it works, but the positioning is way off. It's just occurred to me too, that the height of the bar will need to be the same as #page::before which controls the border. I have edited the question.

You can see it here: https://www.sheree-new.shereewalker.com/

Comment: Hi, Mr Toad. Ok, I think I understand what you mean. So, I edited my answer.

Comment: Hi Andrew that's great thank you! You can see it in action on the site now. However, when I resize the browser it does not recalculate the height, which also causes issues when rotating between portrait and landscape on mobile devices. Is there a way to force it re-calculate on browser resize? Thanks again

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you correctly. You mean when the window resizes, scroll-text element doesn't update its position and is shown outside of the window? I edited a little my code. I also implemented a bit what you're going to do at JsBin, so that you could see how it works for me: [https://jsbin.com/yofidan/edit?output]

Comment: Hi Andrew - yes that is exactly correct. Your JsBin example is perfect but when I paste it in mine, it does not work. I can't work out why? I tried removing all the css and navigation JS that came with the _s theme but incase there was a conflict but no joy.

Comment: Yes, I see... But it's difficult for me to understand what's wrong in your case, because I can't see it under the hood. It seems like some calculations are wrong. I would recommend you to put `console.log`s into `update` and `setSizes` functions and to see what you have there... But.. when I load you website on my phone, everyting looks good, though

Comment: HI Andrew, I'm still trying to get this to work. Looking closer, do you think that your JSbin works because you have a fixed body height? It's the only obvious difference I can see. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi, Toad. I just looked at your site. As I understand, you want to have different logo color depending on the background. So, to achieve this, you used multiple images. But JS code applies only to the first logo element.. that's why the first one works good, unlike the rest. You need to apply this JS code to all the logo elements you have.

Comment: HI Andrew - thanks for your reply. I have applied the javascript to all of them. I have copied and pasted the exact same code into each sections php file. Maybe they need to have different class names for each one.

Comment: Yes, I guess. Try it, so that JavaScript could handle each logo element separately.