# Recalculate scrolling div position when used in a clipping path

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using clipping paths to change my logo colour base on the background colour.

In addition to this the logo scrolls from top to bottom based on the users vertical position on the page. Top of page = logo at top, bottom of page = logo at bottom etc.

Unfortunately when I added the clipping paths the logos lost their scroll position and after the first one, do not work at all.

Is there a way around this? Also, the logo position was a little off to start with so if there is any way of addressing this at the same time.

You can see the original question here:
[div position based on scroll position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57129154/div-position-based-on-scroll-position/57129715?noredirect=1#comment100840522_57129715)

I have tried this, but I can't seem to get it to work.

[Scroll position lost when hiding div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10982548/scroll-position-lost-when-hiding-div)

I am using Advanced Custom Fields and each sections PHP file has this in the header as part of the clipping path using either the white or dark version of the logo accordingly. Its parent is positioned relatively and its child absolutely.

```
div class="logo-scroll">
        <div class="scroll-text">
                    <a href="/home"><img width="53px" height="260px" src="/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/sheree-walker-web-design-edinburgh-vertical-01.svg"/></a>
       </div>
</div>
```

The Javascript

```
const docHeight = Math.max(document.documentElement.scrollHeight, document.body.scrollHeight);
const logo = document.querySelector('.scroll-text');
const logoHeight = logo.offsetHeight;
// to get the pseudoelement's '#page::before' top we use getComputedStyle method
const barTopMargin = parseInt(getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('#page'), '::before').top);

let viewportHeight, barHeight, maxScrollDist, currentScrollPos, scrollFraction;

logo.style.top = barTopMargin + 'px';

window.addEventListener('load', update);
window.addEventListener('resize', setSizes);
document.addEventListener('scroll', update);

setSizes();


function update() {
    currentScrollPos = Math.max(document.documentElement.scrollTop, document.body.scrollTop);
    scrollFraction = currentScrollPos / (docHeight - viewportHeight);

    logo.style.top = barTopMargin + (scrollFraction * maxScrollDist) + 'px';
}

function setSizes() {
    viewportHeight = window.innerHeight;
    // to get the pseudoelement's '#page::before' height we use getComputedStyle method
    barHeight = parseInt(getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('#page'), '::before').height); 
    maxScrollDist = barHeight - logoHeight;
    update();
}
```

The CSS

```
.logo-scroll .scroll-text img {
    padding: 0 6px 0 17px;
}


#page::before {
    content: "";
    position: fixed;
    top: 30px;
    bottom: 30px;
    left: 30px;
    right: 30px;
    border: 2px solid white;
    pointer-events: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 2s; /* Safari prior 6.1 */
    transition: all 2s;
}

.logo-scroll {
    position: fixed;
    left: 30px;
    top: 30px;
    bottom: 30px;
    border-right: 2px solid white;
    width: 75px;
    z-index: 10;
}

.scroll-text {
    position: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let logos, logoHeight, barTopMargin;
let viewportHeight;

window.addEventListener('load', init);
window.addEventListener('resize', setSizes);
document.addEventListener('scroll', update);


function init(lockUpdate) {
    logos = document.querySelectorAll('.scroll-text');
    setSizes(lockUpdate);
}

function update() {
    // ensure initialization and prevent recursive call
    if (!logos) init(true);
    //*************************************************

    /**************************************************
        THIS LINE MUST BE HERE.
    **************************************************/
    let maxScrollDist  = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - viewportHeight;
    //*************************************************

    let currentScrollPos = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    let newTop;

    let middle = currentScrollPos + viewportHeight/2;
    let middleY = maxScrollDist/2;

    if (middle >= (maxScrollDist+viewportHeight)/2) {
        let p = (middleY - Math.floor(middle - (maxScrollDist+viewportHeight)/2))*100/middleY;

        newTop = viewportHeight/2 - logoHeight/2;
        newTop += (100-p)*(viewportHeight/2)/100;
        newTop -= (100-p)*(barTopMargin +logoHeight/2)/100;
        newTop = Math.max(newTop, viewportHeight/2 - logoHeight/2); /*fix*/
    } else {
        let p = (middleY - Math.floor(-middle + (maxScrollDist+viewportHeight)/2))*100/middleY;
        newTop = barTopMargin*(100-p)/100+(viewportHeight/2 - (logoHeight/2)*p/100 )*p/100;
        newTop = Math.min(newTop, viewportHeight/2 - logoHeight/2); /*fix*/
    }

    logos.forEach(function(el) {
        el.style.top = newTop + "px";
    });
}

function setSizes(lockUpdate) {
    logoHeight     = logos[0].offsetHeight;
    barTopMargin   = parseInt(getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('#page'), '::before').top);
    viewportHeight = window.innerHeight;
    if (lockUpdate === true) return;
    update();
}
```

updated and tested.

to check it put this code in your console:

```
document.removeEventListener('scroll', update);
document.onscroll = function() {
    let _logoHeight     = logos[0].offsetHeight;
    let _barTopMargin   = parseInt(getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('#page'), '::before').top);
    let _viewportHeight = window.innerHeight;
    let _maxScrollDist  = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - _viewportHeight;

    let currentScrollPos = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    let percent100 = currentScrollPos + _viewportHeight;

    let scrolledPercent = currentScrollPos * 100/_maxScrollDist;

    let newTop = ((_viewportHeight - _logoHeight/2)*scrolledPercent/100);

    let middle = currentScrollPos + _viewportHeight/2;
    let middleY = _maxScrollDist/2; // 100

    if (middle >= (_maxScrollDist+_viewportHeight)/2) {
        let y1 = middleY - Math.floor(middle - (_maxScrollDist+_viewportHeight)/2);
        let p = y1*100/middleY;

        newTop = _viewportHeight/2 - _logoHeight/2;
        newTop += (100-p)*(_viewportHeight/2)/100;
        newTop -= (100-p)*(30 +_logoHeight/2)/100;

        newTop = Math.max(newTop, _viewportHeight/2 - _logoHeight/2); /*fix*/

    } else {
        let y2 = middleY - Math.floor(-middle + (_maxScrollDist+_viewportHeight)/2);
        let p = y2*100/middleY;
        newTop = 30*(100-p)/100+(_viewportHeight/2 - (_logoHeight/2)*p/100 )*p/100;

        newTop = Math.min(newTop, _viewportHeight/2 - _logoHeight/2); /*fix*/
    }

    logos.forEach(function(el) {
        el.style.top = newTop + "px";
    });
}
```

---

CSS fix:
custom.css :: line 767

```
@media (max-width: 1000px)...
.scroll-text {
    padding-left: 13px;
    /*width: 27px;*/
}
.scroll-text img {
    /* remove it. but if necessary move it to .scroll-text rule above
    width: 27px; */
}
```

custom.css :: line 839

```
@media (max-width: 599px)...
.logo-scroll {
    /*display: none; why! remove it*/
}
```

custom.css :: line 268

```
.scroll-text {
    position: fixed;
    /* height: 280px; remove it*/
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

see this [capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pawWv.gif)

---

finally, have a nice day and goodby.

Comment: Hi there - thanks for this, this is working quite well apart from there is a bit of a lag before it starts moving and for some reason it always stops short at the bottom, the offset amount varies depending on the browser width.

I tried switching from SVG logos to png just incase it was something to do with the sizing but it doesn't make a difference.

You can see it in place at the link in the original post

Comment: Have updated but have no movement at all? Sorry. Thanks!\

Comment: please check it again using console.

Comment: donn't forget updating setSizes function too, and let me see your updates. thanks

Comment: my bad... i have used undefined variable (_viewportHeight)! in setSize function. [fixed] i'm sorry

Comment: Hi there - this is perfect, is it possible to have it recalculate on window resize? I'm thinking for instance such as rotating devices, you need to refresh the page each time. Thanks again for your time

Comment: you need some fix for your CSS rules. the script is perfect and its idea was implemented for the first time for you (my pleasure to help). check update

Comment: "is it possible to have it recalculate on window resize?"!!!! already you have it. window.addEventListener('resize', setSizes); no need to refresh the page each time.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I still cannot get it to work 100% correctly when the page is resized as you can see in the link below but your snippit seems to work. I made those changes to the CSS - the display none at max-width:599px is because I do no use the vertical menu on mobile. Thanks again

https://imgur.com/fVqdvQl

Comment: Yes! That's perfect. Your an absolute star, really appreciate the effort and 
perseverance on this.

Comment: I have realised that this does not work on Safari, the logo does not move at all?  Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but do you have any ideas as to why this would not work on ipad? Thank you so much

Comment: Hmm that did not seem to work. Sorry - I keep coming back to this when time allows

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting only the first 'logo-text'. Instead of:

```
const logo = document.querySelector('.scroll-text');
```

You should use `querySelectorAll`:

```
const logos = document.querySelectorAll('.scroll-text');
```

Then, in your scroll handler, you should move them all.

So, you would then substitute each instance of usage of logo with a loop through the all the logo elements:

```
logos.forEach(logo => logo.style.top = ...);
```

<s>Please be aware that you are doing quite expensive stuff in a scroll handler, which is not great for rendering performance. You might also want to use `requestAnimationFrame` to improve the rendering performance. Check out the [reference page on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/VRDisplay/requestAnimationFrame).</s> Actually, I quickly whipped a version using `requestAnimationFrame` but there was no sensible performance improvement. This is probably due to the fact that apparently rAF fires roughly at the same rate than the `scroll` event. Anyway, I removed it to avoid confusion. If you detect performance issues, let me know.

I suggest, though, that you move the logo using `transform: translate()` rather than `top`. Here you have a complete solution. I tried it in Chrome.

```
const docHeight = Math.max(document.documentElement.scrollHeight, document.body.scrollHeight);
const logos = document.querySelectorAll('.scroll-text');
const logoHeight = logos[0].offsetHeight;
// to get the pseudoelement's '#page::before' top we use getComputedStyle method
const barTopMargin = parseInt(getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('#page'), '::before').top);

let viewportHeight, barHeight, maxScrollDist, currentScrollPos, scrollFraction;

window.addEventListener('load', update);
window.addEventListener('resize', setSizes);
document.addEventListener('scroll', update);

setSizes();

function update() {
  currentScrollPos = Math.max(document.documentElement.scrollTop, document.body.scrollTop);
  scrollFraction = currentScrollPos / (docHeight - viewportHeight);
  const translateDelta = barTopMargin + (scrollFraction * maxScrollDist);

  logos.forEach(logo => logo.style.transform = `translateY(${translateDelta}px)`);
}

function setSizes() {
  viewportHeight = window.innerHeight;
  // to get the pseudoelement's '#page::before' height we use getComputedStyle method
  barHeight = parseInt(getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('#page'), '::before').height);
  maxScrollDist = barHeight - logoHeight;
  update();
}
```

Comment: Hi there. Thank you for this. I changed the line you suggested, but the effect is that none of them now move. 

In terms of using transform: translate() - I am familiar with this use is CSS but I do not know how to integrate that into the JS in place of 'top' as a use supplied me with the original JS here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57129154/div-position-based-on-scroll-position/57129715?noredirect=1#comment100840522_57129715

Though I never got it to work properly.

Comment: @MrToad I have update my answer with an example usage. Today I will be out, but when I get back I will try to provide a better implementation that uses `transform`s and `requestAnimationFrame`.

Comment: Hi @Emanuele - thank you for your time. Sorry to be an idiot, but I can't seem to get these changes to work, though I suspect I might be editing it wrong.

Comment: @MrToad Don’t worry, we’ve all been there. I will provide a complete working solution when I get back home, either today or tomorrow. Cheers.

Comment: @MrToad I added a working snippet I tested on Chrome. Hope it helps.

Comment: @MrToad I forgot to mention that you must set `top: 0` to the `.scroll-text` element to move it to the top of that scroll area, or find another solution for all that.

Comment: Emanuele thank you for your help with this, unfortunately in this case I had to award the bounty to tdjprog but I appreciate your time